# Error opening file using avconv conversion from mp4 to mov

Tags: video, avconv, video-conversion

I'm trying to convert an .mp4 file to .mov file.

The command is as below.

```
avconv -i test1.mp4 kkk.mov
```

.mov file is created but there is an error opening the file. Below is the error.

"Stream contains no data"

I tried using ffmpeg as well. But, that didn't work too. Anyways, as ffmpeg seems to be not in maintenance anymore, I would prefer to go with avconv.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The correct command is

```
avconv -i test1.mp4 -strict experimental kkk.mov
```

If we don't add -strict experimental, the conversion is not properly done.

The same can be used for ffmpeg.